# Update state that has object with multiple keys

Tags: redux

I have a state that looks like this:

`{
  id1: { houses: { name: 'x' }, cars: {} },
  id2: { houses: { name: 'x' }, cars: {} },
  ...
}`

I want to return a state that looks like this:

`{
  id1: { houses: {}, cars: {} },
  id2: { houses: {}, cars: {} },
  ...
}`

That is, I empty the houses entry. I don't know how to do that in an immutable reducer way, given the fact that the state can have many entries (id1, id2, id3,..)

Comment: Is this solved? If not, maybe you need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tricky, but the way I would try to do it is with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
const originalObj = {
  id1: { houses: { name: 'x' }, cars: { dontTouch: 'me1'} },
  id2: { houses: { name: 'x' }, cars: { dontTouch: 'me2'} },
  id3: { houses: { name: 'x' }, cars: { dontTouch: 'me2'} }
};

const initalValue = {};
const objWithResetHouses = 
    Object.entries(originalObj)
        .reduce((acc, [propName, value]) => {
            // "copy" every property, then write over "houses" with an empty object
            acc[propName] = {...value, houses: {}};
            return acc;
        }, initalValue);

console.log(objWithResetHouses);
```